# Migrations, and Seeds using a module based folder structure

Tags: knex.js

I want to use /modules/module_name/ structure for my graphql api so I can later on abstract it/take it out and run as a service in the future.

I have looked/searched knex.js website for how to configure it, and couldn't find it.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  development: {
    migrations: {
      sortDirsSeparately: true,
      directory: ["./src/migrations", "./src/modules/**/migration"],
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./src/seeds",
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

I have tried this configuration, and have not been able to create it to my needs.

Does such a feature exist in knex.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can provide an array of migration directories as you have discovered, it does not appear to support globs. I think you'd be stuck with adding each new directory to the `directory` array as you create each module.